# Accessing resource with expired bearer token fails with 500 http code

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-cloud

Here is my app setup with Spring Boot 1.2.3.RELEASE

**Authentication App**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@SessionAttributes("authorizationRequest")
@EnableResourceServer
public class AuthserverApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(AuthserverApplication.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Principal user(Principal user) {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/oauth/confirm_access").setViewName("authorize");
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(-10)
    protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
                .and().requestMatchers()
                    .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    protected static class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints.authenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients.inMemory().withClient("acme").secret("acmesecret")
                    .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password").scopes("openid")
                    .and().withClient("trusted").secret("shuush").authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials").scopes("openid");
        }

    }
}
```

with application.properties

```
server.port=9999
security.user.password=password
server.contextPath=/uaa
```

**Resource Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Resource
@RestController
public class ResourceApplication {

    @RequestMapping("/resource")
    public Map<String, String> resource() {
        Map<String, String> t = new HashMap<String, String>();
        t.put("Hello", "World!");
        return t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ResourceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

with application.properties

```
server.port: 8801
spring.oauth2.resource.userInfoUri: http://localhost:9999/uaa/user
```

Client Side:

**Step 1** : I use curl to get bearer token

```
curl -v -u trusted:shuush -d "grant_type=client_credentials" http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/token
```

to get a response

```
{"access_token":"a9983ae3-e4db-4702-8039-7ecfd7472594","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":43095,"scope":"openid"}
```

**Step 2** : I access resource

```
curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer a9983ae3-e4db-4702-8039-7ecfd7472594" http://localhost:8801/resource
```

which gets me a dandy response

```
{"Hello":"World!"}
```

**Step 3** : Long after my token as expired I try to access resource again (same as step 2) and I was **expecting a 401 http code** with response something like
    {"error":"unauthorized","error_description":"token expired....."}
however I **get 500 code** with response

```
{
    "timestamp": 1433861559805,
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "exception": "org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException",
    "message": "A redirect is required to get the users approval",
    "path": "/resource"
}
```

Stack trace:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.getRedirectForAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:347)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:194)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:565)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:143)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:262)
    at org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices.getMap(UserInfoTokenServices.java:105)
    at org.springframework.cloud.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices.loadAuthentication(UserInfoTokenServices.java:58)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationManager.authenticate(OAuth2AuthenticationManager.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:150)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Wondering if I am missing some configuration. Any pointers will be appreciated?

**Update 1:**
Oddly sometimes I get different response

```
{"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Possible CSRF detected - state parameter was present but no state could be found"}
```

Little debugging shows the endpoint `http://localhost:9999/uaa/user` does throw error like `{error="invalid_token", error_description="Invalid access token..."}` but is swallowed to throw `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.http.AccessTokenRequiredException` at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/http/OAuth2ErrorHandler.java#L155

Further more `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate` swallows `org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.http.AccessTokenRequiredException` and retries bad token by removing the token at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.0.7.RELEASE/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/OAuth2RestTemplate.java#L143 throws entirely different error.

I believe this is a bug unless something is wrong with my config

Comment: The error is coming from `UserInfoTokenServices` in Spring Cloud. I suggest you raise an issue there. Spring Boot 1.3 has those features too if you want to anticipate the future a bit (i.e. Spring Cloud will be removing it at some point).

Comment: Thank you @DaveSyer .I hope the fix and Spring Boot 1.3 address inconsistent error messaging too